# Is there anyway to get return value in finally statement?

Tags: java, finally

In some legacy code, there are several places to return values. I'd like to log the return value. Is it possible to get the return value in the finally statement?

For example:

```
try {
   if (v == 1) { 
      return 3;
   } else if (v == 3) {
      return x + 2;
   }
} finally {
   // I need to know the return value here, either 3 or x + 2. 
}
```

Comment: Why not log it before you return in the `if` or `else if`statement?  Once you return, it will exit that method.

Comment: no. what you can do is affect a variable, use it in finally, and then return it.

Comment: What value would you like the finally block to see if `v` is neither 1 nor 3?

Comment: Since that's legacy code, I'd like to make as less change as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once `return` is called, everything else in that function is skipped.  If you want to know what the value is there, you're better off saving your `3` or `x+2` in a variable outside the scope of your `try` block.

```
int ret = -1;
try {
    if (v == 1) {
        ret = 3;
    }
    else if (v == 3) {
        ret = x + 2;
    }
}
finally {
    System.out.println("The value of ret is " + ret);
}
return ret;
```

Comment: Might want to move the `return` outside the `finally` block.

Comment: @Andreas, good point.  That's what I get for not keeping up with my Java conventions :P

Comment: This is NOT true. `Finally` block will be called even after function will return its value. Here is a code sample that proves it https://jsfiddle.net/yf9r6n4m/1/

Answer (score 1):

No; a `finally` block doesn't have context into the previous return value.

Your best bet is to store the value off in a variable, log the variable, and return the variable later.

```
int result = 0;
if (v == 1) {
  result = 3;
  log.debug(result);
  return result;
} else if (v == 3) {
  result = x + 2;
  log.debug(result);
  return result;
}
```